# Can you run a 240v US split phase welder on 230v UK single phase

Tags: electrical, welding

I am moving from the US to the UK and would like to know if my welder will work on UK power. The welder is 240V 50/60 hz so that should be fine as I understand it... except, the welder is wired for US split phase so it has 4 wires (L1,L2,N,G) whereas UK power is 230V with only 3 wires (L,N,G) true single phase. Assuming I am correct so far, is there a reasonable way to run a 4 wire 240V split phase appliance on 3 wire, single phase 230V power?

EDIT: Thanks @Three for spurring me to actually open up the welder as it has completely changed my question. I had just (stupidly) assumed the 240V was 4 wire. The welder is wired (as is the receptacle) for 3 wire 240V. So the new (hopefully more accurate) question is-

My welder is wired for L1,L2,G 240V whereas the UK supply is L,N,G 230V. Is there a reasonable way to run or rewire to run a L1,L2,G 240V appliance on L,N,G 230V power?

Comment: Does the welder actually *need* neutral? I would be rather surprised if it actually used the neutral for anything...check to see if the white wire coming out of the cord is actually connected to the welder, or just is landed on a "dummy" terminal and does nothing as a result.

Comment: You need to determine if N is actually connected to anything inside the welder. If it is that thing probably requires 120 V and the welder won't work with a 230 V,  L-N-G connection. Since this is a product use rather than an electrical engineering design or theory question, I am voting to close.

Comment: It's almost certainly connected to the chassis. The last time I looked at a Miller welder (I do SMAW and MIG), that's how it was arranged inside. I only spent about a half hour looking around, though, and I wasn't focused on this question. That said, I'm almost sure (my memory fails) that it wasn't used for anything else. But it's possible that switch lights and so on might be tied that way.

Comment: @jonk -- tying neutral to chassis is improper, actually -- it should be connected to a floating "dummy" terminal if it's not used, otherwise the welder will trip every GFCI it encounters...

Comment: Neutral may be chassis grounded even for 120V http://pdfasset.owneriq.net/b/1e/b1e65127-79fe-4040-be02-9acf903a51bc/b1e65127-79fe-4040-be02-9acf903a51bc-bg3a.png

Comment: @Three It's just what I recall seeing. Pretty obvious. New construction requires dual mode AFCI breakers at the panel (with the usual list of exceptions.) But I don't think GFCI is required at the panel. All the Miller units I've used work off 220 (no one would buy 120) and never that I recall into a dual pole GFCI. I can imagine those for a hot tub. But not for welding. I've never seen it, anyway, and not here at home where I do welding. Could you explain?

Comment: @jonk -- GFCI requirements are being expanded heavily in the 2020 NEC (basically, anywhere that required GFCI on 15/20A 120V receptacles in the 2017 NEC will now require GFCI on *all* receptacles in the 2020 NEC, which means that things like welder receptacles in unfinished spaces will require GFCI protection under the new Code)

Comment: @Three Ah. I've only read up through 2017. And only some of it. Most of what I know comes from 2014 plus some 2017 updates. I'm not a licensed electrician so I read NEC code, updated per Oregon, as a hobby since I do home construction for my community on my own property. (Six adults, three children, for now. I should show pictures, I suppose. Huge "wall of China" just built using JD270 and hundreds of 5000 lb blocks was recently completed.)

Comment: @Three Regardless, thanks for the clue. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not in US or UK. I'd conclude from all the above comments that it MAY not work as is but should be able to be rewired to work without major problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a factory question. The ruling question is whether the machine guts are insulated for 240V.  Because one leg will be 240V from ground.

Is it really worth the shipping expense, though? It takes several times an object's weight in jet fuel to fly it intercontinental. Shipping of course is much better.

Comment: Many overseas moves are done by filling a container with everything from clothes to furniture to dishes, and then weight doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Harper, Don't really understand your answer. I will be filling a 20' shipping container so weight/volume is no problem.